# Alternative to AM and FM transmitting for data transmission?

Tags: serial, uart, radio, data, transmission

So, I need to communicate wirelessly between a micro-controller and my computer. I'm building a radio receiver circuit, and a radio transmitter circuit that works on FM transmission. However, I had an idea.

I'm just transmitting binary. The receiver will go into the micro-controller's UART lane. If I'm transmitting serial data, wouldn't it be easier to simply transmit a specific un-modulated frequency that represents a one, then design the circuit to accept no radio transmission as a zero?

Then the micro-controller program could simply seek out combinations of one's and zeros that it recognized as bytes?

Is there a downside to this that I'm not thinking about? Is there already a name for this kind of rf data transmission?

Comment: [Frequency Shift Keying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frequency-shift_keying).

Comment: Phase modulation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe is called [On-Off Keying](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-off_keying).

It is an extreme version of Amplitude Shift Keying where the carrier is completely off for one value.

This is the technical name for what happens when morse code is sent by a radio operator.

Wikipedia has more information on the pros and cons:

> OOK is more spectrally efficient than frequency-shift keying, but more sensitive to noise when using a regenerative receiver

Comment: *On-Off Keying* is an extreme version of *frequency shift keying* also :)